# Plotting graph visualization of weighted Adjacency Matrix in Julia

Tags: plot, julia, adjacency-matrix, graph-visualization

I have a weighted directed adjacency matrix and I am trying to plot a graph visualization using PlotRecipes.jl. I can't seem to find a way to show both the nodes with labels and somehow represent the edge weights on the edges. I have tried...

```
 graphplot(G, weights=weights,names=names)
```

where G is the adjacency matrix, weights are the edge weights and names is a list of names for the nodes, but I get this output

using just

```
graphplot(G,names=names)
```

I get the same output.
Is there any way to do this with PlotRecipes.jl or is there possibly another library?

Answer (score 1):

You can represent the weights with color (using the `line_z` keyword), but not with line thickness at the moment. cf https://github.com/JuliaPlots/PlotRecipes.jl/issues/39